# Audio and video uploading on Laravel

Tags: laravel, audio, video, package

Hi can please anyone help me how can I upload audio or video file on Laravel is there any package or can someone suggest me a tutorial to learn this because I am a beginner. I am sorry if I am asking to much or something but I thought this is the best place to find the answer that could help me.. 
Thank you, 
Best.

Comment: refer [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/) best place for any laravel beginner

Answer (score -1):

read the documentation about file storage

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem